# User's Speed Data at a Specific Time

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

What should I do to get the user's speed data at a specific time? Is it enough for me to subscribe to the recordClient API?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to basic history session from Google Fit Git repository.
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistorySessions/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistorysessions/MainActivity.java

```
// Build a session read request
        SessionReadRequest readRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
                .setSessionName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME)
                .build();


// Invoke the Sessions API to fetch the session with the query and wait for the result
                    // of the read request.
                    SessionReadResult sessionReadResult =
                            Fitness.SessionsApi.readSession(mClient, readRequest)
                                    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                    // Get a list of the sessions that match the criteria to check the result.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Session read was successful. Number of returned sessions is: "
                            + sessionReadResult.getSessions().size());
                    for (Session session : sessionReadResult.getSessions()) {
                        // Process the session
                        dumpSession(session);

                        // Process the data sets for this session
                        List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResult.getDataSet(session);
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                        }
                    }
```

For more inforation on session just check this link
https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#read_fitness_data_using_sessions

Comment: I will review this. Thank you. So, can the record client be used anywhere in this scenario? Or if we need to try a different method?

Comment: Yes,and accept the answer if you found it useful anyhow, thnks